# Можно ли? Или как? Зная координаты точки и зум или масштаб карты преобразовать координаты картинки(в пикселях) в географические координаты карты?

Tags: python, opencv, pil

Я получаю скрин границ города с Яндекс карты[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Дальше обрисовываю границ города с помощью библиотеки PIL и получаю [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Масштаб скрина и картинки обрисованной в PIL одинаковы(обрезал для примера криво сорри)Нужно преобразовать координаты пикселей картины в координаты географической карты по долготе и широте(x, y).
Цель: Все это нужно для получение координат углов полигона!Нашел метод который будет определять детекторы углов, и тем самым получу координаты углов полигона на Картинке. Пишу на python, есть ли готовые методы? какие то библиотеки на python? итд

Comment: А почему бы не получать границы города по апи?

Comment: Если не учитывать кривизну Земли, то это обычное афинное преобразование. Вам просто нужно рассчитать мартицу для вашего изображения относительно карты, однако, на больших масштабах будет теряться точность

Comment: @eri Нужно именно по картинке)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch по логике вроде понял, в реализации затрудняюсь. Начинающий прогер( не могли бы помочь с реализацией ?

Comment: @Ali если все сделают за вас, то чему вы научитесь?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch основываясь на вашем коде буду учиться! Уже 3 неделю не могу решить эту проблему(

Comment: @Ali в таком случае вам нужно сначала язык программирования подучить, разобраться с векторами и матрицами, разобраться с устройством opencv а уже потом приступать к подобным задачам. Хоть три недели, хоть 10 лет - не зная как складывать 2+2 мало у кого получится решить систему линейных уравнений

Comment: тебе нужно знать координаты 2х-3х точек, чтоб определить масштаб на картинке

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Спасибо, я вас понял.